# Slide Show Not Running Under PHP

Tags: php

Hi I've got this free slider and for some reasons it does not load on my index.PHP but when i change the extension to index.HTML it works like a charm. what might be the problem causing this.

this is the link to my website

http://www.RickTallis.com/index2.php

and here you can find the slideshow loaded with HTML suffix.

http://www.RickTallis.com/cls/

Comment: It looks like those two pages have different content entirely. It could be that the surrounding content is interfering with your plugin.

Comment: changing to .html would prevent php code from being executed (unless you've reconfigured your server to treat .html files as php scripts). So see what in the PHP code is killing the slider.

Answer (score 1):

Using a JavaScript console you can see something like:

```
TypeError: $(".over").preloader is not a function
```

`$` is a function used by many web frameworks, such as jQuery.

And that's it: Currently there are five different versions of jQuery linked on your page. Eliminating four and moving of them helps:

1. Remove lines 28, 57, 88 and 903
2. Change the url in line 20 to `http://www.ricktallis.com/cls/jquery.js`

Hope it helps. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your .php delivers something else than your .html.

Simply compare the output (view source from browser), and you will find differences.

Your code is hard to debug, because of the errors in it (Both HTML and Javascript)

Your HTML seriously needs some cleaning. I see things like 2 end tags for head:

And my javascript error console is soo full after your pageload, I wouldn't know where to start.

And validation of http://www.RickTallis.com/index2.php at http://validator.w3.org gives:

46 Errors, 14 warning(s)

You might just want to clean the mess a little.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked it locally, and problem is in incompatibility between five different version of the jQuery library in single page. After removal, it works well. (Keep only the `jquery.js` in the page. It's on line 88 and put it around line 19 in result page.)